# React(JS) passing a variable declared at mounting to cleanUp function called at unmounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

background - I'm writing a react library. the main component is xarrow. I'm adding event listeners to the DOM so I need to store them and remove them before unmounting xarrow.
I've encountered some strange case and I'm pretty stuck.

the goal: I need a way to remember all event listeners - so at mounting, based on the properties given, I can store any eventListener in an array. and it unmount remove all of them.

what I've tried and the problem:
**declaring `eventListeners` at mounting**  and add all eventListeners to it and return at unmount `()=>cleanUp(eventListeners)` - this way i can remember eventListeners both it mount and unmount. this could have worked great! the problem you asking?? [please see here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-declare-eventlisteners-at-mount-aproch-lx1y1?file=/src/App.js). - here I've changed the code to be almost exactly my real problem -  I have a variable that needs to be initialized at mounting and only after that call `func2` that will change `nums`. but I can't pass `nums` to other useEffect. what can I do?

note - I am aware that maybe my approach to initialize dependent vars at mounting is not the proper way (via useEffects with dependency list)and maybe this is the problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`nums` is not available inside the 2nd useEffect function - only available in the 1st useEffect.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  var nums = [];
  const [iNeedToBeInitialized, setINeedToBeInitialized] = useState(null);

  const func1 = nums => {
    nums.push("1");
  };
  const func2 = nums => {
    nums.push("2");
  };

  const cleanUp = nums => {
    nums = [];
    console.log("nums after unmounting!", nums);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // at mount

    func1(nums);
    setINeedToBeInitialized(true);
    console.log("nums after mounting!", nums);
    return () => cleanUp(nums); //before unmounting - call cleanUp
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // at mount after `iNeedToBeInitialized` has initialized
    if (iNeedToBeInitialized) func2(nums); // i cant pass `nums` to here!
  }, [iNeedToBeInitialized]);

  return <div>i am component</div>;
};
```

Comment: no -  `nums` cannot be declared in the body of the function component because it will be initialized any render. i need to do it once it mounting

Comment: store it in `state` or `ref`?

Comment: @BenWest see why [it is not possible](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-eventlisteners-setstate-aproch-604e5)

Comment: @EliavLouski you will need state then

Comment: I cant use state because useState is asynchronous and the initialization at mounting is synchronous

Comment: So what do you want exactly? print [1] after mount, print [1,2] after state change, and print [] after unmount?

Comment: This is an extremely ugly solution, but I can find no other solutions other than this, so +1